# setAttribute not working correctly. Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong (Im pretty new to js)

Tags: javascript

So what Im trying to do I thought was pretty simple just to help me get a better grasp on simple javascript code. Though from the looks of it, Im having a harder time with it than I originally thought.

Im simply trying to change the yellow square into a black square, heres my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function Change(){
            document.getElementById("boxtwo").setAttribute=("class", "black");
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .red{
            background-color: red;
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            top:37;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .black{
            background-color: black;
            width:180px;
            height:180px;
            top:47;
            left:17;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .yellow{
            background-color: yellow;
            width:180px;
            height:180px;
            top:47;
            left:17;
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="boxone" class="red">
    </div>
    <div id="boxtwo" class="yellow">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnClickMe"
            type="button"
            value="Click Me"
            onclick="Change()">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("boxtwo").setAttribute("class", "black");`

Comment: Please locate the developer console built into your browser. It will provide you with useful error messages.

Comment: ...also, don't use `.setAttribute()` for this. Use `.className = "black";`

Comment: @putvande thanks... stupid equal sign.

Comment: @cookie monster Ill probably use .className = ""; heavily with what Im trying to do. So thanks for that. Are you able to set multiple class names? For instance .className = "black", "yellow"; ?

Comment: @JSArrakis: It's basically equivalent to setting the attribute, but since we're dealing with a DOM now, we prefer properties. So just set the value as you would set the attribute by separating class names with a space. `.className = "black yellow";`

Comment: BTW, the language attribute for script elements was deprecated in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-language) and has been removed from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). It was potentially harmful in some very old browsers but is just a useless anachronism now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

You need to remove the `=` char

```
document.getElementById("boxtwo").setAttribute("class", "black");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo:

```
document.getElementById("boxtwo").setAttribute=("class", "black");
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("boxtwo").setAttribute("class", "black");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute